# How to read data from text file in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

I want to read some data from a text file. The name of the file is 'freq.txt' and it is in the same directory where I compiled the code. The text file looks like:

```
100 cm-1
200 cm-1
300 cm-1
```

The number of lines may vary. I just want to read the number for further processing. Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Did you try a search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813502/reading-input-files-in-fortran

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828377/reading-data-from-txt-file-in-fortran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
program dataread

integer, parameter :: last=3
real :: dat(last)

open(1,file='freq')
do i=1,last
    read(1,*) dat(i)
    write(*,*) dat(i)
end do
close(1)

end program
```

Comment: Better not to use unit numbers under 10.